# Gradle downloading the gson library of 2 different versions 2.9.0 and 2.8.6. How to force it to download only gson 2.9.0

Tags: java, gradle

I am facing a weird issue with Gradle.

I have the below dependency in my gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson.2.9.0
```

But it seems to be downloading gson 2.8.6 too and I am not sure why.

This is causing problems with whitesource as the gson 2.8.6 is flagged for a vulnerability.

I tried doing the below steps

```
implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson') {
        version {
            strictly '2.9.0'
        }
  }
```

and

```
compileOnly('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'){
    force = true
}
```

Further I tried this too

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.code.gson') {
      details.useVersion "2.9.0"
    }
  }
}
...
....
compileOnly 'com.google.code.gson:gson'
```

But none of the above seem to be helping.

Comment: And how is this related to Spring Boot? This seems more of a gradle question (and Spring Boot is just one of the dependencies).

Comment: Sorry let me remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

With `gradle dependencies` you can see what brings this 2.8.6 version, let's call it x.y, with version v, and then add to your gradle.build this:

```
compile ("x.y:v") {
    exclude(module: 'com.google.code.gson')
```

Comment: I see that this is added by this plugin in gradle -> 'org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin' version '1.3.3'

Any idea how I can disable dependencies from a plugin

Comment: I don't understand the above description on how to use it in my gradle file. I also need to know why gson 2.8.6 is still in use.

Comment: It's a CLI. Write it on your terminal, hit Enter, and examine its output. It will contain the answer why gson 2.8.6 is in use.